# green background blinks intermittently (gganimate)

Tags: r

I am trying to animate some figures and get a green background that shows up and disappears intermittently. I have tried to change the duration of animation and frame per second but the issue persists.
Please find below the code.

```r
    anim <- ggplot(airquality, aes(Day, Temp)) +
      geom_point(aes(colour = factor(Month))) +
      transition_time(Day)
```

Comment: Can't reproduce, result of code looks ok on my system.

Comment: Thanks Jon, I will try on another computer to find out.

Answer (score 1):

Try using [magick](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/magick/vignettes/intro.html).

```
anim <- ggplot(airquality, aes(Day, Temp)) +
   geom_point(aes(colour = factor(Month))) +
   transition_time(Day)
animate(anim, renderer = magick_renderer())
anim_save("anim.gif")
```

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. It's not really a gganimate but rather a rendering problem.
It was gone after I restarted my R Session, installed gifski from source and added     `animate(your_animation, renderer = gifski_renderer())`

Comment: Thanks DorianQuelle! Using gifski_renderer did not solve the problem.