# animate time series is giving weird intermediate PNGs with dark green plot fill colors

Tags: r, datetime, ggplot2, time-series, gganimate

I have tried changing several things from confining to single group to changing fps in gganimate. yet no success. Can someone figure why my gif looks like this[image: Some PNGs in GIF]

```
    totalnew$Date <- tsibble::yearmonth(totalnew$Date)
  p3 <- ggplot(totalnew, aes(x = Date, y = value, colour = ecotype)) +
  geom_line() +
  ggtitle("Monthly Methane Emissions") +
  # theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  transition_reveal(as.Date(Date))
```

animate(p3, height = 800, width =800)

Comment: Probable duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66519927/green-background-blinks-intermittently-gganimate and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66576245/why-is-there-some-intermittent-colour-green-when-using-gganimate

Comment: Yes, this is the same problem. Can someone raise an issue? I do use a very old 2013 Mac Pro with i5 and 8 gb ram

Answer (score 0):

This looks like it is working. Seems like a renderer package problem:

```
animate(anim, renderer = magick_renderer())
```